# Python error, Can't import from stdlib error

Tags: python, import

I'm getting at error when trying to import from qtgui site-package.  Here's an excerp from the code that's having and error.

```
from gnuradio import qtgui
```

on of the files in sitepackage qtgui is textparser which contains the statement:

```
from stdlib import read_file
```

That's where the error is thrown.

Following the traceback the problem is that on of the files in qtgui, called textparser.py tries to import read_file from stdlib. 
Here is the traceback of the offending line.

```
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtgui/textparser.py", line 2, in <module>
    from stdlib import read_file
ImportError: No module named stdlib
```

The line "from stdlib import read_file" looks correct except i cant find any information about a package called stdlib for python.  However stdlib sounds like the c library.  I'm new to Python, is that the proper way to import a c library?
So am I missing a python package or module, or a c library?
By the way I'm using python2.7, and Centos 7.  I can't use Python 3 because I'm using GNUradio which i don't think supports Python 3.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no such library in **stdlib** in python there is a library called **stdlib_list** what you gonna supposed to do in your code put a code sample